# Facebook App wall posts redirection

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

maybe its a tricky question but anyway:

I have a facebook application running on an outside server. Lets say my canvas url is

```
http://mydomain.com/myapp/
```

This is integrated into a page, and I can reach the app with an url like

```
http://facebook.com/mypage/app_123456789
```

where 123456789 is my Application ID

Users can share certain things on their walls, and that share contains an url back to my app.

So lets say I have a content shared, it has an url like

```
http://mydomain.com/myapp/content/1
```

This is where the user goes if he clicks on the wall post.

Now my problem is obviously that I want this url to **get redirected** back to my facebook PAGE.

It's easy to redirect everything to

```
http://facebook.com/mypage/app_123456789
```

but that takes me to the main page of my application, not to the specific content the user shared.

Is there a way to do this? Like, I can pass a parameter to facebook to tell which page I want to load?

Comment: Is this a one-off app, or does it need to redirect to several Facebook Pages?

Comment: Hey logan, there is only one page, but the application itself has several contents with different urls, so obviously the user wants to see the specific shared thing he should go to that specific url. This is a problem with canvas applications and page apps alike.

Comment: With canvas applications (but NOT page apps / page tabs), you can just use paths. Ie: `https://apps.facebook.com/onthefarm/myotherpage/` or `https://apps.facebook.com/onthefarm/` or `https://apps.facebook.com/onthefarm/mybest/page1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! Facebook doesn't pass any old parameters you give when being redirected to an application's canvas page, but if you manipulate the parameters in a certain way, you'll gain access to them.

You'll have to pass all your parameters in the following format -

```
https://apps.facebook.com/yourapp?app_data=key1$value1,key2$value2,...
```

Once you reach your canvas URL, you can retrieve the data in `app_data` from within the [`signed_request`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/). Once you have the contents of the parameter, you should have something like this -

```
key1$value1,key2$value2
```

Now it is just an issue of parsing that string into an array of keys and values. In this specific example, I've chosen a dolar character to separate the keys from the values, but as you can see from the code below, you can use whatever you want to separate the parameters and key/value pairs -

```
// initialize parameter array
$getParams = array();
$signedRequest = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
// separate each parameter
$app_data = explode(",",$signedRequest['app_data']);
foreach ($app_data as $param_key => $param_value) {
  // separate each key/value pair
  list($key,$value) = explode("$",$param_value);
  $getParams[$key] = $value;
}
```

At this stage your `$getParams` array should look something like this

```
Array(
  'key1'=>'value1',
  'key2'=>'value2'
)
```

Now that you can pass parameters to your application, you'll be able to decide what content to show according to the data passed to it from the referring URL.